# Insert byte array to an table (blob column - oracle database)

Tags: oracle, vb6

I'm trying to insert a byte array into a table. It has a blob attribute.
This is what i'm doing for setting my array:

```
Dim array() as Byte
Dim lngSize as long

lngSize = FileLen(sFilePath)
open sFilePath for Binary as #1
Redim array(lngSize) as byte
Get #1, ,array
Close #1
```

How can insert this byte array into the table?

Comment: INSERT INTO table ( blobfield ) values ( 0x.... ) where .... are the hex byte of the the array